# TV-series, 1980s, British, city, working-class-people, apartment-block, fall from window, children taken

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

I'm looking for a British TV-series that also aired on Norwegian NRK between 1981 and 1984 - so lets say it may have been made 2-3 years earlier.  I think it was around 6 episodes, though it may have also been a 2nd season/series aired in Norway.  Even more season may have been sent in England.

It's **not** EastEnders - it came later.

It's set in a large(?) city - possible London, but it may have been another (industrial?) city.  It's main focus is an apartment-block - around 8-10 stores high, and if I remember right, rather wide (ie. not sky-scraper shaped).  Probably old and not very modern.  It focus on the people in the block, probably mostly lower-income working-class people.

One episodes ends with a black man falling - or jumping or being thrown - out of one of the windows on the top floor.  The episodes ends with him lying on his back on the asphalt, while very dark blood pools around his head.  I think the episode ends with a close-up of the head and pooling blood.

The episodes - including the above - ended with the picture freezing - possible becoming black-and-white - before the credits rolled over it.

In another episode, social-workers and police take away the kids from a family.  It's 3-5 children.  Not sure if the police is there just to back-up the social-workers, or if the parents gets arrested first.  The children are put into the back of a wan.  Before the wan-door closes, one of the children - a girl around 7 - bend forward to whispers something... when a female social-worker beds forward to listen, the girl gives her a solid "Glasgow Kiss" (head-butts her forehead).  The social-worker makes a few "observations" about the girl, before slamming the door shut.

Does this sound familiar to anybody?

Comment: @Walt Yes, that looks like it.  Guess my memory played tricks on me... in my defense, I was 9 at the time... ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That "Glasgow kiss" from the little girl sounds like a scene from the end of one of the episodes of *[Boys from the Blackstuff](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083689/)* ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boys_from_the_Blackstuff)). I'll see if I can find a clip.

Part 4 - [Yosser's Story](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1249547/?ref_=ttep_ep4). Scene with the headbutt starts at about 50 minutes: